# Is there any way to convert JAVA codes into assembly language(machine language).So that it can be burn on IC(Like microcontroller 8051 or others)

Tags: java, assembly, microcontroller, x86-16, 8051

Is there any way to convert JAVA codes into assembly language(machine     language).So that it can be burn on IC(Like microcontroller 8051 or others).

Comment: No! Java run on JVM and JVM run on your host... You cannot crosscompile java on your architecture

Comment: You used to be able to before Java 7, but not sure if you can now. Check out: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132993/is-it-possible-to-compile-java-into-machine-code-not-bytecode

Comment: You can convert anything to assembly, you just need to know the assembly language like an expert and create the appropriate compiler that works on Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 3):

Building a compiler is mostly a matter of sweat.  But the 8051 has a very small address space, typically 4K bytes of ROM and only 128 bytes of RAM.
**This means a practical compiler would have to have many restrictions to make it anywhere near workable, let alone practical or attractive.**

First, the ROM space would limit the size of any Java program considerably; almost everything from the JDK would not fit.  You can't afford to have most of List or String or even Object; toString is likely to an unaffordable luxury.  Your data types are almost certainly restricted to 8 bit ints; 32 and 64 bits ints are probably totally impractical.  IEEE floating point is out of the question, because of the code space it would take to support it; you could implement a simpler format floating point but it would take a good chunk of the ROM (I've coded floating point on a number of small processors).
You can't have very many objects; there isn't enough space.  Worse, you probably cannot afford to allocate them dynamically because the memory space that would be required to access them (based pointer + offet), so "new" would have to be outlawed or treated in a really restrictive way.  Garbage collection is completely impractical. So it is likely that objects used by the program must "magically" exist when your program starts.   How would one specify that?  (Maybe main contains all the "new" calls, and they are compiled statically, but even that might take precious code space better spent on something else.

A really serious problem is that Java does not have user-level I/O.  How would the program talk to the hardware?  One klunky answer is to make a giant object that covers all the special purpose registers, so they could be accessed as field values.  This rather violates the Java language design, in that fields only change because of program reads or writes, but the special function registers can change due to hardware conditions.  So this solution would change the langauge to be not-quite Java.

One of the 8051 best features is bit-addressing.  Java doesn't do bit addressing; at best it addresses bytes.  So you either lose that (and your program blows up in space) or you add funny operators to model the bit addressing.   Again, not-quite Java.

Throw and catch with dynamic error objects is probably out of the question.  If you force the error objects to be statically allocated you might make this work.

Most microcontrollers end up controlling several I/O points, that are arguably asynchronous.  You couldn't use Java tasking for this.  You might resort to polling; that's not much worse than how that would typically be coded on many simple microcontroller programs.   The 8051 can handle interrupts; there's no standard way to set that up in a Java program.  You can kluge the language to add an interrupt keyword; back to not-so-java.

Building a compiler with all these restrictions could probably be done.  The remaining language would resemble Java but would not allow one to write any conventional Java programs, so its unclear what the actual benefit is.  A conventional Java programmer would have to re-learn how to code in this langauge.

**It doesn't seem to have any positive benefits.**

If you insist on a compiler, I think you'd be better off with a [C compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8051_compiler).    Some of these compilers can handle a lot more ROM space.  Using their techniques you might overcome some of the consequences of space limitations I discussed above.  But an 8051 and large memories are kind of incompatible; the whole point of an 8051 is to be cheap, cheap, cheap [as it is its single-chip form] and adding external memory removes some of the cheapness.

For complex programs, you probably have to fall back to assembler to enable you to write clever enough code to shoehorn the code and data necessary.   Some machines are best programmed near the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to read this paper (just 3-4 pages): [Byte code Interpreter for 8051 Microcontroller](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/IMECS2010/IMECS2010_pp1125-1129.pdf)

Comment: Is there any book available for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any book about, but that paper's 'references' sections may help you to find out something.

Answer (score 0):

Java is normally compiled to "bytecodes"; the bytecodes are normally executed by a Java Virtual Machine.  One way to run them on your controller would be to write a Java Virtual Machine that ran on the controller; whether this is possible depends on the architecture of the controller.  Whether it is practical depends on that plus other things.

It is certainly possible to compile Java code directly to an assembly language, assuming that the architecture of the target processor supports the operations embodied in the bytecodes.  Whether one already exists is a separate question.

Comment: There are also compilers, e.g. [gcj](https://gcc.gnu.org/java/), which supports cross-compilation